# LotusScript NotesDateTime.AdjustDay affect other NotesDateTime object

Tags: lotusscript

In LotusScript agent I'm trying to decrement a NotesDateTime object by one day.

I've:

```
Dim date1 As NotesDateTime("Today")
Dim date2 As NotesDateTime
Call date1.SetNow
Set date2 = date1
Call date2.Adjustday(-1)
```

My question is, why decrementing object date2 by one day is also decrementing date1 object?

Answer (score 2):

date2 points to the same NotesDateTime object as date1 because of

```
Set date2 = date1
```

You copy the reference to date1's object only, not the value. After this code line you have still only one instance of a NotesDateTime object. date1 and date2 are referencing this same object.

Comment: Expanding on what Knut said, if what you really want is two distinct datetime values, then you  can just change your fourth line of code to 'date2.localTime = date1.localTime()'. That will set date2 to the value of date1, instead of setting date2 to a reference to date1.